# Off page connector using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm creating a flowchart using TikZ. You can see my code so far below.

But now I want to create an off page connector:

[image]

I don't have a clue how to implement this in my `\tikzset`.

Furthermore I want to create two flowcharts on one page, is this possible?
Lets say this flowchart below once on the right side of the page and once on the left side of the page.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
%   offpageconnector/.style = {draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) --     cycle, fill=orange!20},
    decision/.style   = {diamond, draw, fill=orange!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
    block/.style      = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=1cm},
    terminator/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=1cm, node distance=3cm},
    line/.style       = {draw, -latex'},
    cloud/.style      = {draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=1.5cm, minimum height=2em},
    subroutine/.style = {draw,rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=3,minimum height=1cm, rectangle split part fill={green!50}},
    connector/.style  = {draw,circle,node distance=3cm,fill=purple!20},
    data/.style       = {draw, trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=1cm,node distance=3cm,fill=olive!20},
    cloud/.style      = {draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node [cloud] (start) {Start};
\node [block, below of=start,node distance=2cm] (init) {Init};
\node [block, below of=init,node distance=2cm] (1ebyteop) {$1^{e}$ byte ophalen};
\node [decision,below of=1ebyteop,node distance=2cm] (contreof) {EOF?};
\node [terminator, right of=contreof] (end1) {END};
\node [block, below of=contreof] (2ebyteop) {$2^{e}$ byte ophalen};
\node [decision,below of=2ebyteop,node distance=2cm] (contreof2) {EOF?};
\node [terminator, right of=contreof2] (end2) {END};
\node [subroutine, below of=contreof2, node distance=2cm] (sub1) {\nodepart{two} SUB1};
\node [subroutine, below of=sub1, node distance=2cm] (sub2) {\nodepart{two} SUB2};

% Draw edges
\path [line] (start) -- (init);
\path [line] (init) -- (1ebyteop);
\path [line] (1ebyteop) -- (contreof);
\path [line] (contreof) -- node {yes} (end1);
\path [line] (contreof) -- node {no}(2ebyteop);
\path [line] (2ebyteop) -- (contreof2);
\path [line] (contreof2) -- node {yes} (end2);
\path [line] (contreof2) -- node {no}(sub1);
\path [line] (sub1) -- (sub2);
\path [line] (sub2) |- ($(sub2.south west) - (0.7,0.7)$) |- (1ebyteop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, you can use the `shapes` library and `shape=signal` with `signal to=south`.

For the second question, there are many options: one of them might be to use a `scope` with an appropriate `xshift` and another option would be to use `minipage`s (one can put the `minipage`s inside a figure environment to obtain a floating object with captions); the following example illustrates both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzset{
page con/.style={shape=signal,draw,fill=olive!30, signal to=south,text width=5em,text height=1.5em,align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node[page con] at (0,2) {test};
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\node[page con] at (0,2) {test};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[page con] at (0,2) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[page con] at (0,2) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Another test figure}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    offpageconnector/.style = {draw,
                               single arrow,
                               single arrow tip angle = 90,
                               single arrow head extend = 0pt,
                               shape border rotate=270,
                               text width=5em,
                               text badly centered,
                               fill=orange!20},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[offpageconnector] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]